# Windows Azure: Unsupported expression null

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service

Suddenly the azure is throwing this error upon hosting site. It is running locally, but not upon hosting. It looks like `where({...})` is causing the issue.

```
authenticateUser(user){
        var table = this.client.getTable("user").where({ id: user.id, password: user.password });
         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            table.read()
                .done(function (items) {
                    if(items.length > 0) resolve(items[0])
                    else resolve(false);
                }, function (error) { reject(error) });
        });
    }
```

It is throwing this error.

[image]

The where client is working for external library i.e `<script src="//zumo.blob.core.windows.net/sdk/azure-mobile-apps-client.2.0.0.js"></script>` However if i am using the npm package, then it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug here with the minified bundle to do with variable name mangling. This issue has been reported here: [table.where(whereclause).read() doesn't work on minified version #249](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/issues/249).
To aviod this issue, please upgrade the version to `2.0.1`.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for the research. However, I am using the npm package of 2.0.1, and I am still having that issue.

Comment: They just disabled minification of the part of code where this error happens. If you install the npm package and minify yourself the error persists.